# Adding one linq line to my function calls

Tags: c#, linq, protocol-buffers

I am trying to add a linq line to a MapField (Google protobuf).

My actual code works fine like

```
 private static MapField<string, TestResultProto> dToP (Dictionary<Uri, TestResult> keyValuePairs)
    {
       MapField<string, TestResultProto> keyValues = new();
       foreach (var pair in keyValuePairs)
       {
          keyValues[pair.key.ToString()] = TRTP (pair.value);
       }
       return keyValues;
    }

private static TestResultProto  TRTP (TestResult tr)
{
   
    TestResultProto t = new()
    {
        id = tr.id;
        email = tr.email;
    };
    return t;
}
```

And now I use the above methods.

```
object o = //something;
Class1 c = new Class1();
c.Results.Add(dToP(o.Results));  // This works as expected
//c.Results is a MapField<string, TestResultProto>
//o.Results is Dictionary<Uri, TestResult> keyValuePairs
```

So, to write the above line, I was thinking to add a linq like :

```
**c.Results.AddRange(o.Results.Select(TRTP))); //ERROR**
```

Here, I get the error in the linq (above line), saying no method for AddRange for MapField. So, there is something like AddEntriesFrom, but the signature is it expects Codec. Any idea on how to do it ?

Comment: [Docs](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/class/google/protobuf/collections/map-field-t-key-t-value-) say MapField has an `Add(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> entries)` - Dictionary is-a IDictionary, but you're doing a manipulation of the key/value types in your loop; you could do that with LINQ if you wanted.. (but what do you gain, really?)

Comment: We are doing linq at most places, so wanted to do that, but how, can you help out on that ?

Comment: LINQ is for querying data, not for modifying objects. Don't use LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

If you're desperate to turn it LINQ you could do something like:

```
private static MapField<string, TestResultProto> dToP (Dictionary<Uri, TestResult> d)
{
   var m = new MapField<string, TestResultProto>();
   m.Add(d.ToDictionary(
       kvp => kvp.Key.ToString(),
       kvp => new TestResultProto 
         {
           id = kvp.Value.id,
           email = kvp.Value.email
         }
   ));
   return m;
}
```

Comment: Note: I have no way of testing this; if I made some minor typo, feel free to edit the answer. If I made a major mistake, let me know so I can review